# Why default value in functional React component gets updated after render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I struggle to understand why do I get different values logged in the console in this React component:

```
const MyComponent = () => {

  // Initialise data with a random value:
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(
    () => {
      const data = _.sampleSize(_.range(5), 3)
      // Print data on initialisation:
      console.log('init data in default:', data)
      return data
    }
  )

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Print data after the component is rendered:
    console.log('init data after render:', data)
  })

  return (
    <div>{data}</div>
  );
};
```

The output in console is:

```
[Log] init data in default: – [0, 3, 1] (3)
[Log] init data after render: – [2, 1, 3] (3)
```

and the component is rendered to: `<div>213</div>`

But why the values are different?

My understanding is that before the component is rendered, the function under `useState` is called. The value returned by the function is assigned to `data`, and the `data` values is used to render the component on the screen. The function under `useState` is called only once and we never call `setData`, so the value should be the same. What do I miss?

**UPD:** I tried to create a code snippet, it is the first time I use `codesandbox`, so please let me know if it does not work:
https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-glade-9jm75?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It's got something to do with `<StrictMode>`. Remove that from your index.js and the issue goes away. But i havn't put all the pieces together yet to give a full answer.

Comment: Definitely `StrictMode` at work, it invokes render twice and thus calls `useState` twice and since `sampleSize` returns random elements the random selection from the second render is what is picked up by `useEffect`.

Comment: Hmm, but why then `console.log('init data in default:', data)` prints only once? I thought I should at least see that the function under `React.useState` is called twice.

Comment: React 17, React automatically modifies the console methods like console.log() to silence the logs in the second call to lifecycle functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) causes React to run components twice, to detect various possible unsafe sections of code. It's a bit like a limited runtime linter.

In it:

> Starting with React 17, React automatically modifies the console methods like console.log() to silence the logs in the second call to lifecycle functions.

The first time the component is called, the `console.log` in the `useState` call runs, logging the first data generated.

This first call does not get fully rendered; the `useEffect` never runs. Instead, React runs the component again to check for inconsistencies. On the second run, the `console.log` in the `useState` is suppressed.

Then, later, on the second run, the component truly finishes rendering properly, and its effect hook runs, which logs the data generated previously (but not shown in the console).

[Here's a post describing a very similar issue](https://dev.to/sebastianstamm/be-careful-with-console-log-when-using-react-strictmode-ah9).

Comment: Ok, the mystery is solved then. But it is quite unexpected behaviour. You do not see that the component is re-rendered and the output is different. Good to know! Thank you for the detailed answer